# Can night shift be untied from automatic dark mode?

Tags: macos, monterey, dark-mode, night-shift

I have "Appearance" set to auto, which makes dark mode kicking in at the sunset. I'd like to have night shift shifting to warmer colours at 10pm, shortly before I go to bed, **not at the sunset**.

However, they seem to be tied: if I just schedule the night shift it sets the appearance to light mode immediately if I'm already on dark mode, and it prevents dark mode starting if it hasn't started already. Then, when night shift starts, dark mode starts as well.

[image]

I couldn't find any duplicate target with the tag [night-shift](/questions/tagged/night-shift), googling it gives a couple of pages claiming they are tied, no further explanation.

Are they really tied? Can I have the dark mode starting at dusk but the night shift only later?